# Could not get lock ... Resource temporarily unavailable after running sudo apt update (Error 11)

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

I have a fresh installation of Ubuntu 18.04-x64.

In the terminal I enter the command:

```
sudo apt update
```

And I get the following error:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
```

When I run `sudo apt update` again, the command runs successfully and I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done                                                  
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
103 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

This behaviour is consistent. I have a VM snapshot of the fresh Ubuntu installation and everytime the first `sudo apt update` fails with this error and the second `sudo apt update` completes successfully.

EDIT: Should have mentioned that the `sudo apt update` command lies inside a script. Running the script with sudo privileges seems to have fixed the problem.

Comment: As you have learned, it is unwise to use 'sudo' within a script. Glad to see you seem to have solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That issue is happening because the system identifies the fact the lock file is being used by another process. You can identify the process and kill it by

```
$ps aux | grep -i apt
$sudo kill -9 <pid>
```

If something happened during an `apt-get` process, like a system shutdown, then there will be no process having the file locked, by the problem will still be there. In that case you can reconfigure the necessary files, as follows:

```
$sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
$sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
$sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
$sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Comment: So if I'm running the `sudo apt update` command inside a script, should I add those two lines in front of it to ensure it runs correctly?

Comment: You haven't mentioned that this is happening inside a script. It might be that the script does not have insufficient permissions. So try running it with `sudo`. What I wrote you above, is in case the problem occurs into the terminal operations.

Comment: I'm pretty new to shell scripting so I assumed that what is written inside a script is executed just as if I typed it out to the terminal, one line at a time

Comment: That is the case. But if you simply run the script by `./script.sh`, then the script might not have the sufficient permissions to complete the operations you automated.

Comment: @CrispJam If you have dealt with the issue, accept the answer or the comments of it, to help others find the solution to a similar problem.